# node.js nested callback, get final results array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am doing a for loop to find the result from mongodb, and concat the array. But I am not getting the final results array when the loop is finished. I am new to node.js, and I think it's not working like objective-c callback.

```
app.get('/users/self/feed', function(req, res){
    var query = Bill.find({user: req.param('userId')});
    query.sort('-createdAt');
    query.exec(function(err, bill){
        if (bill) {
            var arr = bill;
            Following.findOne({user: req.param('userId')}, function(err, follow){
                if (follow) {
                    var follows = follow.following; //this is a array of user ids
                    for (var i = 0; i < follows.length; i++) {
                        var followId = follows[i];
                        Bill.find({user: followId}, function(err, result){
                            arr = arr.concat(result);
                            // res.send(200, arr);// this is working.
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    res.send(400, err);
                }
            });
            res.send(200, arr); //if put here, i am not getting the final results
        } else {
            res.send(400, err);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not entirely familiar with MongoDB, a quick reading of their [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/) shows that they provide an ***asynchronous*** Node.js interface.

That said, both the `findOne` and `find` operations start, but don't necessarily complete by the time you reach `res.send(200, arr)` meaning `arr` will *still* be empty.

Instead, you should send your response back once ***all*** asynchronous calls complete meaning you could do something like:

```
var billsToFind = follows.length;
for (var i = 0; i < follows.length; i++) {
   var followId = follows[i];
   Bill.find({user: followId}, function(err, result){
      arr = arr.concat(result);
      billsToFind -= 1;
      if(billsToFind === 0){
         res.send(200, arr);
      }
   });
}
```

The approach uses a counter for all of the inner async calls (I'm ignoring the `findOne` because we're currently inside its callback anyway). As each `Bill.find` call completes it decrements the counter and once it reaches 0 it means that all callbacks have fired (this works since `Bill.find` is called for every item in the array `follows`) and it sends back the response with the full array.

Answer (score 0):

That's true. Your codes inside `for` will be executed in parallel at the same time (and with the same value of `i` I think). If you added `console.log` inside and after your `for` loop you will found the outside one will be printed before inside one.

You can wrap the code that inside your `for` into array of functions and execute them by using `async` module (https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) in parallel or series, and retrieve the final result from `async.parallel` or `async.series`'s last parameter.